# Android TextView autocomplete and autosearch

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have some contacts autocomplete and autosearch algorithm working for my android app.
First some xml to define the text view for the input:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        a:id="@+id/recipientBody"
        a:layout_width="0dip"
        a:layout_height="wrap_content"
        a:layout_weight="1.0"
        a:nextFocusRight="@+id/smsRecipientButton"
        a:hint="@string/sms_to_whom"
        a:maxLines="10"
       />
```

And now I setup the text view

```
AutoCompleteTextView recip =
        (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.recipientBody);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, getAllContacts());
        recip.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And now the actual algorithm that searches for a contact that matches the input:

```
private List<String> getAllContacts() {
        List<String> contacts = new ArrayList<String>();
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    Cursor pCursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                                            null, 
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", 
                                            new String[]{contactId}, null);

                    while (pCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        String phoneNumber = pCursor.getString(pCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));                      
                        contacts.add(phoneNumber + " ( " + displayName + " )");
                    } 

                    pCursor.close();
                }
            }
        }       
        return contacts;
    }
```

This works fine for both contact number and name input. But there is still a problem. The user can input multiple phone numbers. But when one contact is applied to the text view it cannot search again, because the algorithm takes the whole string.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Well, I thought about it for a while and spotted a problem with my solution - there's no place where you could insert the contact from the completion list into the TextView.

The solution seems to be [MultiAutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MultiAutoCompleteTextView.html), this thing is designed for solving your problem.

Sorry for confusion!

---

For me, it looks like you need a custom adapter.

You may extend `ArrayAdapter<String>` and implement `getFilter()` - of course you will also need a custom filter (extending `Filter`) which instance you will return from that method.

Filter's `performFiltering` method has one parameter - the string for which the list of suggestion is needed. You need to take the part after the last comma (or whatever character are you using as a separator) and return the suggestion list for that substring.

P.S.

For the better user experience, you may also think of styling your AutoCompleteTextView contents with Spans: http://ballardhack.wordpress.com/2011/07/25/customizing-the-android-edittext-behavior-with-spans/